# mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

Tags: php, apache, centos7, fastcgi, plesk

Too many visitors receive 500 Internal Server Error and the following errors.

Website hosted on Plesk and I have slow performance

```
[Fri Jul 24 15:36:56.229095 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 11030:tid 140710274152192] (32)Broken pipe: [client x.x.x.x:33554] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: https://www.example.com
[Fri Jul 24 15:37:59.216097 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 10897:tid 140710124689152] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client x.x.x.x:35644] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://www.example.com
[Fri Jul 24 15:38:56.341408 2020] [core:error] [pid 10763:tid 140710149867264] [client x.x.x.x:34208] End of script output before headers: x.php, referer: https://www.example.com
```

fcgid.conf

```
<IfModule !mod_fastcgi.c>
   AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl
</IfModule>

 FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid/sock
 FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm

 FcgidIdleTimeout 40
 FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
 FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500
 FcgidMaxProcesses 20
 FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
 FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
 FcgidConnectTimeout 3600
 FcgidIOTimeout 3600
 FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
 FcgidIdleScanInterval 10
 FcgidBusyTimeout 3600

</IfModule>
```